# Read file in a folder using regex expression in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to read a file from a folder using the below code in my local and s3. For now I am testing in my local.

```
#job_date_str = "2021-08-03T05:20:00"
path = f'{config["input"]["logs"][job]}{job_date_str}(.)*'
# also tried path = f'{config["input"]["logs"][job]}{job_date_str}*'
dataframe = spark.read.schema(schema).json(path, multiLine=multiline)
```

The folder has file inside directory(config["input"]["logs"][job]) as **2021-08-03T05:20:00.000-31bnrrpUT5qNLtEX8zWt.log.gz. (YYYY-MM-DDTh:m:s.000-something)**

It is throwing me error as

```
21/08/03 12:12:49 ERROR logger: error: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 2021-08-03T05:20:00.000-31bnrrpUT5qNLtEX8zWt.log.gz in get_json
```

not sure what does it mean.
**here I have file names starting with job_date_str**

But earlier I was trying to read files using.

```
#job_date_str = "2021-08-03T05:20:00"
path = f'{config["input"]["logs"][job]}{job_date_str}/*'
dataframe = spark.read.schema(schema).json(path, multiLine=multiline)
```

and It worked in local and s3. **here I was storing files inside job_date_str** directory.

Comment: Apparently, `path` value is `2021-08-03T05:20:00.000-31bnrrpUT5qNLtEX8zWt.log.gz` which is considered as an relative path. And you are supposed to give an absolute path, which means something that starts with `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck in this and found out the spark cannot handle `:` in the file name, I changed `:` with `-` and now it is working as expected.

I found this there:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-13

Still look like an issue if someone cannot change `:` in the filename. 
If anyone finds a solution to this please do post it.